# Why does RouteLink generate friendly URL while ActionLink does not?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, actionlink

I have a question regarding RouteLink vs. ActionLink.

Consider the following route

```
routes.MapRoute("Routename1",
    "{someEnum}/SpecificAction/{id}/{stringId}",
    new { controller = "MyController", id = (int?)null, stringId= (string)null, action = "SpecificAction" },
    new { someEnum= "(EnumVal1|EnumVal2)" }
);
```

The weird {someEnum} part is because I use a general controller for all values of an enum that form the typical controller part of a url. For instance, /EnumVal1/Action/ and /EnumVal2/Action/ use the same controller. That's not part of the problem, however.

Consider the following two ways of linking:

```
<%=Html.RouteLink("Click me","Routename1", new { id = 32, stringId = "Yatzy" })%> 
<%=Html.ActionLink("Click me", "SpecificAction", "EnumVal1", new { id = 32, stringId = "Yatsy" }, null)%>
```

The RouteLink generates the correct url, which would be /EnumVal1/SpecificAction/32/Yatzy

The ActionLink generates an url that looks like /EnumVal1/SpecificAction/32?stringId=Yatzy

Why is this? Could someone explain this to me, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RouteLink` [can only ever use the one route you specify](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/03/18/38085/). `ActionLink` will use the first matching route, whether it's the one you intended or not. Your two examples are probably matching different routes.

[Phil Haack's routing debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) would help clarify this.

Comment: Hi. This was my initial thought as well, but when I entered the given URL into the debugtool, for instance: /EnumVal1/SpecificAction/32/Yatzy, - it matches the same route that I use for RouteLink (It's also the only route that matches).

Comment: You're confusing URL parsing with link generation. They're two different sides of the routing coin. That URL parsing works does not mean that `ActionLink` generation will also match the route you expect.

Comment: Oh. How would I use the routing debugger to see the right side of the coin? :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem here: `RouteLink` does exactly what you want, and it's faster than `ActionLink`. Why not just use it?

Comment: I am using RouteLink, - the question I posed was an attempt to find out why one of them generated a friendly URL, while the other didn't.